# Changing value in dtsConfig file from c# code

Tags: c#, xml, ssis

I have a dtsConfig file with configuration for ssis package variable User::Quote_ID:

```
<Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" 
Path="\Package.Variables[User::Quote_ID].Properties[Value]" 
ValueType="String"><ConfiguredValue>77777</ConfiguredValue></Configuration>
```

I want to change this value from c# code:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(@"\\MyServer\DataFiles$\...\MyConfigFile.dtsConfig");
XmlNode xFile = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("User::Quote_ID");               
xFile.Value = quote_ID.ToString();
xDoc.Save(@"\\MyServer\DataFiles$\...\MyConfigFile.dtsConfig");
xDoc = null;
```

It gives me an error on the third line of my code (XmlNode...):

‘User::Quote_ID’ has an invalid token

What is wrong?

Comment: are you familiar with XPath? you can do this using that.. do a quick google search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node name is "Configuration". Within that, you have an attribute called "Path", whose value is "\Package.Variables[User::Quote_ID].Properties[Value]".

I'm not sure what you need to do in your code, but here is an example of one way to go about making changes in that value:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(@"\\MyServer\DataFiles$\...\MyConfigFile.dtsConfig");
XmlNode xFile = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("Configuration");
xFile.Attributes["Path"].Value = xFile.Attributes["Path"].Value.Replace("User::Quote_ID", "newValue");
xDoc.Save(@"\\MyServer\DataFiles$\...\MyConfigFile.dtsConfig");
xDoc = null;
```

The above example will change `\Package.Variables[User::Quote_ID].Properties[Value]` to `\Package.Variables[newValue].Properties[Value]`.

**Updated Example**

This will replace the `77777` value with `quote_ID.ToString()` (I'm assuming the `55555` is in there) for the first node (for all nodes, remove `break;`) where the 'Path' is `\Package.Variables[User::Quote_ID].Properties[Value]`.

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(@"\\MyServer\DataFiles$\...\MyConfigFile.dtsConfig");
XmlNodeList listOfConfigurationNodes = xDoc.SelectNodes("Configuration");
foreach (XmlNode node in listOfConfigurationNodes)
{
    if (node.Attributes["Path"].Value == @"\Package.Variables[User::Quote_ID].Properties[Value]")
    {
        node.SelectSingleNode("ConfiguredValue").InnerText = quote_ID.ToString();
        break;
    }
}
xDoc.Save(@"\\MyServer\DataFiles$\...\MyConfigFile.dtsConfig");
xDoc = null;
```

Comment: But I don't want to replace the variable name with the variable value. I want to replace the variable value to the new one, for example, 77777 to 55555. And another problem: I have many nodes with name "Configuration" - one for each variable. How the program will know that I want to change the value for this particular variable "User::Quote_ID"?

Comment: I've included an updated example that explains how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Chris! Your code helped me a lot! In my case it did not work thought. I ran the application in debug mode and I could see that xDoc.Load... opens the right file, but it did not execute foreach loop. The property listOfConfigurationNodes had Count = 0. I checked my xml file again and found that it has outer node  and all  nodes inside this outer node. So I changed your code

```
XmlNodeList listOfConfigurationNodes = xDoc.SelectNodes("Configuration");
```

I made:

```
XmlNode XMLOuterNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("DTSConfiguration");
XmlNodeList listOfConfigurationNodes = XMLOuterNode.SelectNodes("Configuration");
```

This code works fine for my particular case. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Awesome! Another option you can use to "jump" straight to the nodes you want is to use double slashes, like `"//Configuration"`, although I tend to prefer the way you did it as it's potentially less risky when you make more of the path explicit. You can also reduce the code to one line and say `XmlNodeList listOfConfigurationNodes = XMLOuterNode.SelectNodes("DTSConfiguration/Configuration");`.

Comment: Correction: `XmlNodeList listOfConfigurationNodes = xDoc.SelectNodes("DTSConfiguration/Configuration");`.